# Spring boot не видит контроллеры

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Есть практически базовое приложение на Spring Boot v.1.5.7.

Главный класс:

```
package ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("Application started");
    }
}
```

и два конфигурационных файла, Spring Security:

```
package ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

и Web MVC:

```
package ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

Если конфигурационные файлы лежат в одном пакете с Application.java то всё хорошо. Как только начинаю "раскидывать" конфигурационные файлы по пакетам - всё перестаёт работать.

[Ссылка на репозиторий Github](https://github.com/bajiepka13/10webapplication/tree/master/src/main/java/ua/com/bajiepka)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot должен как-то узнать, в каких пакетах искать компоненты, сервисы, сущности и репозитории:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ 
  "ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication.somepackage",
  "ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication.anotherpackage" 
})
@EntityScan(basePackages="ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="ua.com.bajiepka.webapplication.models")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    ...
}
```